# Is there any special C++ function to get XOR of all element of array?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have an array like this `[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, ...]`.

How can i get result of this expression: `1 XOR 0 XOR 1 XOR 1 XOR...` without loop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++14:

```cpp
std::accumulate(arr.begin(),
                arr.end(),
                0,
                std::bit_xor<void>())
```

Comment: OP didn't state type of array, so (`int`)`0` might be adjusted to correct type.

Comment: Yes, to be entirely correct and general we need to replace `0` with `static_cast<decltype(*arr.begin())>(0)`. But OP's example shows just integers with value 0 and 1 in which case this is fine.

Comment: I think `std::decay_t`/`std::remove_reference_t` is needed in that case.

Comment: @Jarod42 Quite possibly, it's been a while since I've written fully generic C++ code.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a function template that takes an array and forwards to a helper function using `make_index_sequence` - which then uses a fold expression to "unpack" the array.

This does not require any loop since the expression will be created at compile time.

```cpp
#include <utility>

namespace detail {
template<class T, std::size_t... I>
auto Xor_helper(const T& arr, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    // make a fold expression of the whole array:
    return (... ^ arr[I]);      // arr[0] ^ arr[1] ^ ...
}
} // namespace detail

template<class T, size_t N>
auto Xor(const T(&arr)[N]) {
     return detail::Xor_helper(arr, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

And you could call it with your array like so:

```
int main() {
    int arr[] = {0xf, 0x1, 0x3};

    std::cout << std::hex << Xor(arr) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
d
```

You can see what becomes of these templates @ [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/ed13b3da). Just press the <kbd>▶</kbd> button and you'll see the above `Xor(arr)` become `return (arr[0UL] ^ arr[1UL]) ^ arr[2UL];`

---

The fold expression above require at least C++17. A solution that works from C++98 and forward could use recursion instead.

Example:

```cpp
namespace detail {

template<std::size_t> struct index_tag{}; // one type per index used

template<class T, size_t N, size_t I> // main function template
T Xor_helper(const T(&arr)[N], index_tag<I>) {
    // recurse using `index_tag<I - 1>`:
    return Xor_helper(arr, index_tag<I - 1>()) ^ arr[I];
}

// Recursion stops when `index_tag<0>` is used:
template<class T, size_t N>           // terminating case
T Xor_helper(const T(&arr)[N], index_tag<0>) {
    return arr[0]; // no recursion, just return the value
}
} // namespace detail

template<class T, size_t N>
T Xor(const T(&arr)[N]) {
    // Call the helper using the index_tag for the last index in the array:
    return detail::Xor_helper(arr, detail::index_tag<N - 1>());
}
```

You can also see how these templates will be instantiated @ [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/df6a924b).

Answer (score -3):

It worked:
`std::accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), arr[0], std::bit_xor());`

Comment: You should accept @orlp's answer instead of repeating it.

Comment: @MattTimmermans, I've posted my solution before update page and noticed his answer, so I didn't saw it.

Comment: I downvoted your answer, not because I was first, but because yours is incorrect. It will include `arr[0]` twice in the XOR computation, thus cancelling it out. Try computing it on `std::array<int, 1> arr = {1};` and you'll see that it incorrectly returns 0. It also segfaults if `arr` is a zero-sized sequence.

Comment: Yup, this is wrong. You should start accumulating from 0 instead of arr[0]. @orlp's answer is the right one